# Searching for a string in Objects held in a Vector

Tags: java, vector

I am facing some problem getting my head around Java Programming.

Basically, I have a class named Workers, and one of its instance variable is nameOfWorker.
I then stored all the instances of class Workers in a Vector v.

Now what I am having trouble with is, I do not know how to check a particular worker's name (suppose John) in all the instances of Workers held in my Vector v.

How do I do this?

Also, after I have found a match for John in one of the Worker objects in the held in the vector, how do I access the instance methods stored at that location in the vector?

Hope I have been able to clearly state my problem. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, you most likely don't want to use `Vector`, you want to use `List<E>`. Second, what's wrong with a good, old `for(int idx)` or `for(Worker worker : workers)` loop? Third, `Worker.nameOfWorker` is superflous...you want `Worker.getName()`.

Comment: @Bobby in modern days, you'd rather go `for(Worker w : workers)` loop. Also, the fact they're using a `Vector` is an implementation detail, you cannot tell they "want to use `List<E>`", for you lack context information to assert this.

Comment: @Romain: Not if he wants the position. ;) But true, using for each and instead of the position saving the instance is way better!

Comment: @Romain: That's why I said "you most likely want to" given that OP states "...getting my head around Java Programming." which sounds like a newcomer (maybe from C/C++, which has a Vector class, too).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use iterator for that, or you can also use index based access.

```
for (Worker w : vector) {
    System.out.println("Worker Name: " + w.getNameOfWorker())
}
```

Ensure that you add `getNameOfWorker` getter method in case it is missing in the class.